# Custom rounded linear layout : add borders

Tags: android, android-layout

I have developed a custom rounded `LinearLayout` and I want to add 1px border.

Here my code :

```
public class MyLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

private float radius;
private Path path = new Path();
private RectF rect = new RectF();


public MyLinearLayout(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    radius = 20;
    setWillNotDraw(false);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    path.reset();
    rect.set(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    path.addRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, Direction.CCW);
    // Add 1px border RED here ?
    path.close();
    canvas.clipPath(path);
}
```

}

Thanks for your help.

Comment: hmmmm... why not using an xml shape drawable? it would be easier.

Comment: No I can't because I change color dynamically and I can't use the SetBackground method.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the rounded corners in your custom `LinearLayout`, you will probably see that the radius is not smooth. This is because there is a system limitation that does not support anti aliasing on `Paths`.

Here is a great [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jF6Ad4GYjRU0) from Erik Burke on how to properly create `Views` with rounded corners. Basically you will create an off-screen `Bitmap`, draw a `RoundRectangle`, and use an alpha compositing technique to merge the off-screen `Bitmap` with the custom `LinearLayout` `Canvas`' `Bitmap`.

As far as a border, you can can draw it by setting `Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE` to the `Paint`.

Comment: Thank you for this great tutorial. Problem is I don't want to use Drawables. I just want to get a rounded linear layout, with a border.

Comment: Right, you can do the border via code using the `Paint` class.

Comment: Humm I don't see how to do that. Have you got an example ?

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is to make your off-screen bitmap a pixel smaller than the width and height of your `LinearLayout`. Then you give the `LinearLayout`'s `Bitmap` a color. Then the border will show.

Comment: I want the color only displayed on 1px border, I don't want to fill the rounded layout by a color...

Comment: Exactly, that is what I am suggesting you do. I guess it is hard to explain without a picture. The outer most `Bitmap` will be one pixel larger than the inner most `Bitmap`. Then since you will use alpha compositing the bottom `Bitmap` will be merged to the top `Bitmap`.

Comment: If this solved your question, please mark the question as answered.